# Table background color change every secon row

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change color background of table, but it change only row divided by 2. how can i change the rest?

I'm attaching the code of the table and the relevat CSS.

CSS

```
.table-striped{
  background: #f8fcff !important;
  .label {
    width: 44px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
```

]

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use nth child.

This will allow you to edit what rows you want to style

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/M6BM7/)

```
table tr:nth-child(odd)
{
background:red;
}

table tr:nth-child(even)
{
background:blue;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I haven't thought of this. Is this supported by all common browsers?

Comment: @Dropout It is, apart from ie8 and older

Comment: @Bruse is that that what you want it to look like or is that what's happening?

Comment: I get blue for even, and the odd rows are white

Comment: Yap, but for some reason it doesn't work on my web... I can't undersatnd why

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time zebra striping is achieved by assigning certain classes to elements when the page is prepared. For example if you have the following structure

```
<div id='table'>
    <div class='row odd'></div>
    <div class='row even'></div>
    <div class='row odd'></div>
    <div class='row even'></div>
</div>
```

you can simply create a CSS specifying certain rows attributes based on the `.odd` and `.even` selectors.

There's also an option to do this post process using JS/jQuery, however it's obviously not the best way to go.